# AWS EC2 Python Parallel - Extremely slow

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to run Monte-Carlo simulation with Python in EC2, AWS. However, whenever I try to run a paralleled program with more than 2 processes, it becomes extremely slow, even slower than without any parallelization.

EC2 Instance: Ubuntu + c5d.9xlarge(36 cores, 72GB) + Python 3 + Jupyterlab

A toy example:

```
def  test(i):
    t = time.time()
    a = randn(200,200)
    b = a.T.dot(a)
    c = scipy.linalg.sqrtm(a)
    print(time.time()) - t
pool = Pool(N)
pool.map(test,range(10))
```

1. When N = 2, each takes about 0.04s, the total takes 0.26s (which is close to the performance on my MBP, either single-task or paralleled. This issue does not happen to my MBP)
2. When N = 4, each takes about 0.26 - 0.8s, the total takes 0.9s

I understand (thanks to @aws_apprentice) in such a simple example, the swapping process may dominate. But in my real f, which is about 2-min long, such an issue still exists and a simple "scipy.linalg.sqrtm" dominates the time cost. That is really weird to me.

1. It seems that only happens to some operators/functions: when I try just

```
def test1(i):
    t = now()
    for j in range(10):
        randn(1000,1000)
    print(now() - t)
```

it was fine. But it also happened to "np.sum()".
However my simulation has "sqrtm" and "sum" inside, so I found that the two parts will become extremely slow.

3. I tried different EC2 instances, and the issue is always there.

I was trying to utilize the multi-cores of EC2  to run, for example, 1000 repetitions with different seeds. And this issue makes it impossible.

Any comments or suggestions are highly welcomed! Thanks!

Comment: based on this simple example, you are incurring the cost of spawning multiple processes, these are not free and have overhead which is why simple CPU bound tasks, like in your toy example, work better when running without a pool

Comment: @ aws_apprentice Thank you so much! I am not an expert in CS. My task is very simple, I just want to run, for example, 1000 independent tasks with different seeds, and I thought it would be quite straightforward (as before on a PC). So what would you suggest to do? Thanks

Comment: you can run them in parallel if you want, there's lots of things to consider, are they CPU or I/O bound. also you wouldn't want to run all of them at once, you would want to limit it to the number of cores the machine has + 2, which is a general rule of thumb. this question is a bit too broad for this site unfortunately...

Comment: Thank you! I do want to run in parallel. But as you see, the example only has one "scipy.linalg.sqrtm", and I can not see why there should be an issue. For the numbers, my instances have 36 cores, and I try to run 10 repetitions with 2/4 processes, however this still happens. Even with this toy example, I can not easily run 1000 repetitions when setting n_processes = 10.

Comment: @aws_apprentice  I see what you are saying.  Do you mean the action to "trying to generate 10 subprocesses" causes unnecessary time cost and make it slower in my toy example? Actually, in my program, one repetition takes about 2 mins, in which "sqrtm" is only a part (but when paralleled, while makes 2 become 5). And this also not happens to my MBP.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. It seems that this issue is owing to that multiprocessing and OMP (therefore some Numpy and Scipy?) does not work well together, due to some multi-threading things(My limited understanding)? Anyway, after running the following code first, everything works as expected:

```
import os
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
```